# using variable as attribute - error: Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to get this to work with a string

```
binance.prices((error, ticker) => {

  console.log("Price of BTC: ", ticker.BTCUSDT);
});
```

returns the correct value (price of BTC) however,

```
var coin = "BTCUSDT"

binance.prices((error, ticker) => {

  console.log("Price of BTC: ", ticker.[coin]);
});
```

returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`. I've asked around and haven't been able to get any help on this.

Comment: Use either `.` or `[ ]`, not both.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
console.log("Price of BTC: ", ticker.coin);
```

or

```
 console.log("Price of BTC: ", ticker[coin]);
```

Comment: or for the purposes of the OP, `ticker[coin]`

Comment: The dot was the problem. I deleted it and it worked, thank you guys!